# Hide/visible app mode in iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

1.We have opened app.
2.Then we hide it.
3.Then we repair it .
4.And after that action i need to update page.
how can i realize it?

Comment: Please be more precise:
1. How do you 'hide' the app?
2. What does 'repair' mean?
3. What will the 'update' do?

Comment: too many questions!!!!!!

Comment: Do you mean, the app is opened, then the user presses home, then goes back into the app, and at that point you want to do something?

Comment: 1. I click central button in iphone 2. i click icon in bar 3. I need reload page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities for this:

1) When reactivated, the method `applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your application delegate will be called. Note that this will also be called when the app is being started for the first time.

2) An `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is being posted to the notification center. Objects (views) that need to react to that may register for that notification. I think this would probably the way to go for your case: register for this notification in the view that needs to be reloaded. Registering for notifications is handled in [Notification Programming Topics - Registering for Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-CEGCCFID)